# python socket client program 2(Get request)

Tags: python, sockets

Thanks all for solving my first question.But there is a final problem.

```
#import socket module

import sys
import httplib
from socket import *
serverName = sys.argv[1]
serverPort = int(sys.argv[2])
filename = sys.argv[3] 
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,serverPort))
clientSocket.send("GET /filename")
while True:
    data = clientSocket.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print data,filename
clientSocket.close()
```

FInally, i can't receive the content with the certain filname.I think the point is in "/"
How can i solve it??

Comment: What *do* you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [python requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) package?

Either way, you have a problem here:

```
clientSocket.send("GET /filename")
```

Should (at the very least) be:

```
clientSocket.send("GET /%s" % filename)
```

When you write `filename` inside the string, it will not evaluate that to the variable `filename` instead, you need to use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)

Answer (score 1):

Is this program communicate with HTTP server?

Then, it should send CR+LF twice to correctly denote the end of HTTP header.

```
clientSocket.send("GET /{}\r\n\r\n".format(filename))
```

Comment: I am connected to socket server.But can u tell more about \r\n\r\n? It is about the knowlege of http potocol?

Comment: @user2877854, `\r\n\r\n` is there to separate http header from http body.  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.1